# Veslink reported consumption and VIP reported consumption are different

Tags: forms

Seabulk is using veslink forms in order for the vessels to send bunker information to VIP. There is a problem with the consumption calculation in the Vessel Departure Report.

To explain, we go to the test environment and go to ‘define and send forms’:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK2iP.png)

Find the ‘Vessel Departure report’ on the second page of the forms page:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLPrq.png)

Click ‘configure’ and ‘advanced’:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipeLu.png)
Then ‘XML test’ and select the below vessel:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRtFV.png)

When we go to the form and fill out the ROBs, the veslink form’s consumption is not correct.

Vessel view:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/apLPj.png)

VIP view:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z8a1.png)

When I submit the form to VIP, the consumption is corrected. An error is noted in the submission however.

I tried sending multiple forms after testing the following settings:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC8JH.png)

I also tried sending arrival forms prior to departure forms so that the Previous ROB might populate.